# Object with application/pdf breaks on visibility change of parent element

Tags: html, pdf

Given the following snippet:

```
<script>
    function show(id)
    {
        for(let i = 1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            const elem = document.getElementById("pdf-box-"+i);
            if(i === id) elem.style = "";
            else elem.style = "display:none";
        }
    }
</script>

<button onclick="show(1)">Show #1</button><br/>
<button onclick="show(2)">Show #2</button><br/>
<button onclick="show(3)">Show #3</button><br/>

<div id="pdf-box-1" style="display:none">
  <object data="https://maio290.de/lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf"  height="800" width="95%"></object>
</div>

<div id="pdf-box-2" style="display:none">
  <object data="https://maio290.de/lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf"  height="800" width="95%"></object>
</div>

<div id="pdf-box-3" style="display:none">
  <object data="https://maio290.de/lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf"  height="800" width="95%"></object>
</div>
```

Since this didn't seem to work in Stackblitz - you can try it yourself clickable [here](https://maio290.de/pdf.html).

I can display all the PDFs fine - but only once. As I unhide the parent element, the object doesn't get rendered properly. This [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1218930&q=component%3AInternals%3EPlugins%3EPDF) is present in the current Chromium based browsers (Microsoft Edge & Chrome tested) - Firefox doesn't seem to be affected. As I resize the window, the PDF is getting displayed again.

Has anyone encountered this bug and found a viable solution? The application I'm having this problem with is actually based on JSF with Primefaces. Therefore I cannot change their logic to hide/show elements properly. I also would like to keep the `object` tag for displaying PDFs and only use an `iframe` using static `pdf.js` as a last resort.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those wondering how to bypass this issue: The easiest way to force the browser to re-render is to add a margin value. If that isn't applicable, you may fiddle around with other CSS attributes.

I ended up using the following code for JSF & Primefaces:

```
                <ui:fragment rendered="#{request.getHeader('user-agent').contains('Chrome')}">
                    <script>
                            function fixChromePDFBug()
                            {
                                const documentTabParent = document.getElementById("form:documentFiles");
                                documentTabParent.removeAttribute("style");
                                documentTabParent.style = "margin: "+Math.random()+"px";
                            }
                            
                            function execDelayed()
                            {
                                setTimeout(fixChromePDFBug, 300);
                            }                           
                                            
                            
                            function addListenerToTab()
                            {
                                const documentTabParent = document.getElementById("form:documentFiles");
                                const anchors = documentTabParent.getElementsByTagName("a");
                                
                                for(let anchor of anchors)
                                {
                                    anchor.addEventListener("click",execDelayed, false);
                                }
                                
                            }

                            addListenerToTab();
                    </script>
                </ui:fragment>
```